# ActiveRecord retrieve records in HABTM relationship that belong to array of associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

`Maintenance` HABTM `MaintenanceOrders`

Given an array of `MaintenanceOrder` ids: `[1,2,3,4,5]`, how can I retrieve all the `Maintenances` associated with those `MaintenanceOrders`?

Tried this:

```
@paired_things = Maintenance.where(maintenance_order_id: [1,2,3,4,5])
```

But it rightly failed because `maintenance_order_id` isn't a column on Maintenance, and of course that doesn't make sense because it's a HABTM relationship...

This is the join table from schema:

```
create_table "maintenance_orders_maintenances", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer "maintenance_order_id"
  t.integer "maintenance_id"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `includes`, for example:

```
Maintenance.includes(:maintenance_orders).where(maintenance_orders: {id: [1,2,3,4,5]})
```